# Customizing ClickOnce installer

Tags: clickonce

I need a post action on ClickOnce installer which should be performed after the application files are stored on the client side but before the application's first run. Specifically, I would like to encrypt sections of a configuration file.

From what I've found, it's possible to add a class containing InPlaceHostingManager methods and use it for explicit installation/updates later on, but how can one override the default ClickOnce installer so that custom code is called?

I would like to emulate the behavior of the ancient Setup Project which invokes the Install method of whatever inheritor of System.Configuration.Install.Installer you plug into your project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with ClickOnce.

As I see it some of your options include:

1. Going back to an MSI installer
2. Encoding the config files as a pre/post-compile step on the development/publishing machine then deploy the fully encoded version
3. Encoding the config files on [first run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isfirstrun.aspx) of the app (if you find a way to ensure they aren't being locked)

Also, you mentioned InPlaceHostingManager. It looks to me that it's a way of hosting the ClickOnce installation framework (rather than doing it via IE for example). So this might let you make a custom installation application to host the installation and run the post-installation steps, but the problem is that you'll still need to install your custom installation application somehow (and run it as a user with installation rights)...

Comment: How would you decode the files client side? You need a kind of central authority to distribute the keys/

Comment: Regarding encryption, it's been a long time since I worked with it, but you would distribute the public key with the application. After all, it's a public key, so it can go out into the world without worry... For the subsequent post-deployment encryption, you could use a local key pair of some kind - whether it's generated or supplied somehow will be up to you but your app just has to trust that it's the only one that knows about the private key.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do the encoding of the files first thing when your application runs before it does anything else? Is it really too late?

You can use the InPlace Hosting Manager to update a clickonce application. You can use it to install one, the only gotcha is that you have to have the .NET Framework installed ahead of time, or write some small exe in C that will check for it (can't be managed code).

See if this helps you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like to encrypt the connectionStrings section before the app has a chance to run.

Comment: You should actually encrypt the connection strings before deploying the application. If you're not going to do that, then it doesn't really matter if your app encrypts them or something else encrypts them.

Comment: Could not find a really good solution, so I had to implement a component serving connections using SSL. Once retrieved, they are stored and encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FirstRun**.

**Namespace**:  System.Deployment.Application

**Assembly**:  System.Deployment (in System.Deployment.dll)

Method will call on First Window.

```
private void DownloadFileGroupSync(string fileGroup)
        {
            if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                ApplicationDeployment deployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

                if (deployment.IsFirstRun)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (deployment.IsFileGroupDownloaded(fileGroup))
                        {
                            deployment.DownloadFileGroup(fileGroup);
                        } 
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This application is not a ClickOnce application. Error: " + ioe.Message);
                        return;
                    }

                    downloadStatus.Text = String.Format("Download of file group {0} complete.", fileGroup);
                }
            }            
        }
```